# How to run a java class on ubuntu?

Tags: java, ubuntu, classpath, execution

If I compile and run the program. I don't have any issues.

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Prints "Hello, World" to the terminal window.
        System.out.println("Hello, World");
    }
}
```

If I add the line `package ch01.sec01;` it complies correctly with *javac*. However when I try to run it using `java` I get:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class HelloWorld
```

I have tried the following.

```
export CLASSPATH=/usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.9.0-openjdk-amd64/bin
```

Comment: We'll need the complete command line you used.  Your classname is not `HelloWorld` it's `ch01.sec01.HelloWorld`.

Comment: I used javac HelloWorld.java

Comment: When you have a `package ch01.sec01` the class file is written to `cg01/sec01/...`.  You must use the full name.

Answer (score 2):

That is why when you use a `package` in your code, that path must be the actual path of your java file (That means that your code is supposed to be in a directory called **sec01** which is inside directory **ch01**).
With that being set, when running code inside a package, you need to include the path in the command. To do so, after you have compiled your code with `javac`, navigate to the root of the path (outside ch01 directory) and type

```
java ch01.sec01.HelloWorld
```

This should work.